# Meteor - Multiple collections in one collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, schema

I'll try and make this short. I'm looking to make a form that will have four inputs, then with the push of a button, I can add another four identical inputs directly below the first, and do this for nth number of times. When I submit at the end, whether I have the original four input fields, or 7 more duplicates of the four fields, how can I save however many as one item in mongo?

For example:

First | Last | Age | Grade 
submit

or

First | Last | Age | Grade
First | Last | Age | Grade
First | Last | Age | Grade
First | Last | Age | Grade
submit

Answer (score 0):

As an array of objects in a mongo document:

```
[
  { first: "Joe", last: "Blow", age: 15, grade: "A" },
  { first: "David", last: "Bloom", age: 15, grade: "B" },
  ...
  { first: "Bob", last: "Long", age: 15, grade: "C" }
]
```